# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to wake up after suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, hp

I've tried many answers over here to solve this problem, but none of them work.
I use a HP-Pavillion with Intel 620 graphics, and have a 1tb ssd and 12 gigs of ram.

I've dual-booted the system with Windows 10, and the system does wake with Windows 10.

The system also used to wake up before I reinstalled Ubuntu.

I've noticed that the display is just completely black, but the keyboard does light up.

`Ctrl-Alt F3` or `F7` don't work either.

My swap space is as follows:

```
$sudo swapon --show
NAME           TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/home/swapfile file 8.5G   0B   -2
```

I've tried setting `noveau.modeset=0`, and also switching to `lightdm` from `gdm3`, to no avail.

I checked system logs using `journalctl | grep systemd-sleep` and got this result.

```
Aug 12 21:58:30 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]: Suspending system...
Aug 12 23:32:31 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]: System resumed.
Aug 12 23:32:32 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]: /dev/sda:
Aug 12 23:32:32 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 12 23:32:32 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 12 23:32:33 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]: /dev/sda:
Aug 12 23:32:33 abcd systemd-sleep[14314]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 13 20:23:32 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]: Suspending system...
Aug 13 21:01:35 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]: System resumed.
Aug 13 21:01:35 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]: /dev/sda:
Aug 13 21:01:35 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 13 21:01:35 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 13 21:01:35 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]: /dev/sda:
Aug 13 21:01:35 abcd systemd-sleep[7730]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 13 21:43:40 abcd systemd-sleep[3007]: Suspending system...
Aug 14 22:05:42 abcd systemd-sleep[3004]: Suspending system...
Aug 15 19:43:55 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]: Suspending system...
Aug 15 22:42:15 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]: System resumed.
Aug 15 22:42:16 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]: /dev/sda:
Aug 15 22:42:16 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 15 22:42:16 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 15 22:42:16 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]: /dev/sda:
Aug 15 22:42:16 abcd systemd-sleep[2051]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 16 15:16:11 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]: Suspending system...
Aug 16 17:13:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]: System resumed.
Aug 16 17:13:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:13:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 16 17:13:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 16 17:13:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:13:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1405]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 16 17:15:04 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]: Suspending system...
Aug 16 17:21:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]: System resumed.
Aug 16 17:21:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:21:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 16 17:21:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 16 17:21:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:21:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1567]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 16 17:23:47 abcd systemd-sleep[1681]: Suspending system...
Aug 16 17:23:54 abcd systemd-sleep[1681]: System resumed.
Aug 16 17:23:55 abcd systemd-sleep[1681]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:23:55 abcd systemd-sleep[1681]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Aug 16 17:23:55 abcd systemd-sleep[1681]:  APM_level        = 254
Aug 16 17:24:00 abcd systemd-sleep[1767]: Suspending system...
Aug 16 17:24:06 abcd systemd-sleep[1767]: System resumed.
Aug 16 17:24:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1767]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:24:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1767]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Aug 16 17:24:07 abcd systemd-sleep[1767]:  APM_level        = 254
Aug 16 17:25:51 abcd systemd-sleep[1860]: Suspending system...
Aug 16 17:25:59 abcd systemd-sleep[1860]: System resumed.
Aug 16 17:26:00 abcd systemd-sleep[1860]: /dev/sda:
Aug 16 17:26:00 abcd systemd-sleep[1860]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Aug 16 17:26:00 abcd systemd-sleep[1860]:  APM_level        = 254
Aug 16 17:26:03 abcd systemd-sleep[1942]: Suspending system...
Aug 16 21:35:51 abcd systemd-sleep[9438]: Suspending system...
Aug 18 15:42:35 abcd systemd-sleep[1988]: Suspending system...
Aug 18 16:25:37 abcd systemd-sleep[4224]: Suspending system...
Aug 18 17:22:14 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]: Suspending system...
Aug 18 18:54:59 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]: System resumed.
Aug 18 18:55:00 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]: /dev/sda:
Aug 18 18:55:00 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 18 18:55:00 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 18 18:55:00 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]: /dev/sda:
Aug 18 18:55:00 abcd systemd-sleep[3314]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 18 18:55:24 abcd systemd-sleep[3477]: Suspending system...
Aug 18 19:25:17 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]: Suspending system...
Aug 18 20:11:47 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]: System resumed.
Aug 18 20:11:48 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]: /dev/sda:
Aug 18 20:11:48 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Aug 18 20:11:48 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]:  APM_level        = 128
Aug 18 20:11:48 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]: /dev/sda:
Aug 18 20:11:48 abcd systemd-sleep[1488]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Aug 18 20:11:50 abcd systemd-sleep[1625]: Suspending system...
```

So it does in fact resume after sleeping
Does anyone have any idea on what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.